# What will be an O(n) solution for this?

Tags: algorithms, dynamic-programming

Suppose a given piece of work can be done at two processors. One at `r` and another at `v`. The job can run only at one processor at a time.

```
r = R1, R2 ... Ri, ...Rn

v = V1, V2,... Vi, ...Vn
```

There is a time penalty to switch between `r` and `v`, which is a constant say `k`. But I will have to maximize the total work done within `x` hours.

`Xi` represents the amount of work done in the `i`th minute.

I was thinking that comparing the `Vi` and `Ri` every minute and then if one is greater than the other by `k` make a switch. But that won't be optimal.

How can this be approached?

Comment: Welcome to [cs.SE]! Can you add a url or reference to credit the original source?

Comment: @Apass.Jack Unfortunately I don't have either.

Comment: If you do not have either, how do you discover or know this problem? Please provide some background.

Comment: @Apass.Jack Total time is limited. How can you do all?

Comment: Note that I suspect this might be a part of ongoing programming contest, since no reasonable source has been provided. You could claim this is from your own work, in which case, a little bit explanation of background would be much appreciated. Just note that all history here are preserved. Sorry, I have been tricked before by others.

Comment: It seems similar to assembly line scheduling DP problem. You can take a look at that problem if it helps.

Comment: @JotWaraich Yes, that's what I found. And that is the type of solution I am going with. Thanks.